# how i can make the Revenue Sharing system by php

Tags: php

How can I show something on 75% of requests, so that on average, every four page requests would result in three pages showing it, and one not.

> **this is a translation of this question!...**
>
> i dont know how it working with 70%
>
> now how i can show in example echo
>   iam; in a page in 70% percent
>
> this mean it will appear 3 times and
>   one not

Comment: great, who could translate this? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fool proof way I can think to do this is:

```
if (($pageHits % 10) < 7)
    echo 'iam';
```

Comment: Page hits is the number of times that page has been requested. You would have to get this value yourself, in your own way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether I got you correctly but you can do this:

```
$i = rand(0,3);
if($i < 3) {
    echo 'foo';
}
```

This will echo `foo` in 75% of all visits.

Comment: but this can echo 'foo'; 4 times because its random

Comment: @moustafa: Yes, but according to the law of big numbers, in the long run you will get 75%.